# Problema ao obter dados do usuário no localStorage da aplicação

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, localstorage

Galera eu gostaria de implementar um menu "minha conta" no meu projeto, este menu deve mostrar os dados do usuário como nome, email etc, estou usando jwt e os dados do usuário logado podem ser obtidos no LocalStorage neste formato:`{"id":"598a8bc8b9dd44250819a7c4","name":"bruno","username":"kinge880","email":"brunomaya10@hotmail.com"}`
Gostaria apenas de saber como acessar esse array e pegar o name dentro dele estou usando nodejs, angular 4 e mongodb

Comment: localStorage.getItem("name")?

Comment: No localStorage tenho apenas meu user, dai usando getItem("user") eu recebo aquele array ali em cima, o que quero saber é como acessar o array e pegar um valor dentro dele, no caso, name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `localStorage#getItem` retorna uma `String`, portanto é necessário fazer a conversão para objeto utilizando `JSON#parse`:

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
var name = user.name;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado ;)

Comment: @BrunoMaia Não esqueça de acetar a resposta como correta para que o alguém com dúvida similar possa usufruir da solução